# How do I hide the Hangouts panel on Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

On the Google+ website (plus.google.com), the Hangouts panel appears on the right hand side.  I already have the Chrome Hangouts extension so I don't need it there at all.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on "Hangouts" [image: "Hangouts" icon] at the top of the sidebar.

[image: Hangouts panel open]

[image: Hangouts panel closed]

Comment: You know, I tried *everything* else, except for that.